# Don't add authorization attribute in request header in .NET project

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly

In my old project in Blazor WASM and ASP.NET Core Web API, I use a `customAuthenticationStateProvider` and login for getting token for set in local storage, finally send request with token in request header for access to authorize endpoint in controller but in this project not set token in request header:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    #region Dependency
    protected ILocalStorageService LocalStorageService { get; }
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider
                        (ILocalStorageService localStorageService,
                         HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        LocalStorageService = localStorageService;
        HttpClient = httpClient;
    }
    #endregion Dependency

    #region Methods

    #region GetAuthenticationStateAsync
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState? _state = null;

        var _token = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync(key: "Jwt-Id-Token");

        var _claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token) == false)
            {
                _token = _token.Replace("\"", "");

                HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: "Bearer",
                                                                                               parameter: _token);

                _claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims: ParseClaimsFromJwt(_token),
                                                     authenticationType: "jwt");
            }

            var _claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity: _claimsIdentity);

            _state = new AuthenticationState(user: _claimsPrincipal);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task: Task.FromResult(_state));
        });

        return _state!;
    }

    #endregion GetAuthenticationStateAsync

    #region ParseClaimsFromJwt

    private IEnumerable<Claim>? ParseClaimsFromJwt(string token)
    {
        var _payload = token.Split('.')[1];
        var _jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(_payload);//Json-Bytes
        var _properties = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(_jsonBytes);

        //var _claims = _properties!.Select(p => new Claim(p.Key, p.Value.ToString()!));

        var _claims = new List<Claim>();

        foreach (var property in _properties!)
        {
            var _key = property.Key;
            var _value = property.Value is null ? string.Empty : property.Value.ToString();

            var _claim = new Claim(type: _key,
                                 value: _value!);
            _claims.Add(_claim);
        }

        return _claims;
    }

    #endregion ParseClaimsFromJwt

    #region ParseBase64WithoutPadding

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }

    #endregion ParseBase64WithoutPadding

    #endregion Methods
}
```

In another project, I use this code for setting token in request header:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: "Bearer", parameter: _token);
```